# Electron/React/Redux - How to load a local file in an action creator?

Tags: reactjs, redux, ipc, electron

I am working on an Electron/React/Redux app that uses NeDB for a local data store (though this problem is not really about NeDB I think). I can use ipcRenderer.send to make calls to load the local data store but I am unclear on how to do this in the context of a redux action creator since the way I get the data back is via the ipcRenderer.on listener.

An action creator that obviously doesn't work...

```
export function getData() {
  ipcRenderer.send('getData');

  return {
    type: GET_DATA,
    payload: // WHAT IS THE PAYLOAD?
  }
}
```